# Is it possible to optimize a COUNT query by adding a max number of rows to count on?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a complex query, that I need to optimize.

It has a single select column, which is a COUNT().
A lot of joins (like around 10) and a simple Where clause.

It looks something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.Id) AS count
FROM dbo.tableA a
JOIN dbo.tableB b ON(a.Id = b.tableAId)
JOIN dbo.tableC c ON(b.Id = c.tableBId)
...
WHERE c.User = @user AND d.state = @state
```

The query can count thousands of rows. However I only need it to count up to 100.
Is there a way to specify a TOP 100 or LIMIT 100 for the count itself? Not the actual query?

I could extract the query, add TOP 100 and then do count on the result. However that seems to defeat the purpose of optimization.

Comment: So are you actually just trying to get SQL Server to see if there are *at least* 100 rows?

Comment: No, I need to count up to 100. I just want to know if there is a way to omit counting over 100. I do not need to know that the count result is 5022 for example.

Comment: I'd try SELECT DISTINCT in a derived table, with an OFFSET 0 FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY.  Then COUNT its result.

Comment: To get it to stop after it finds the 100th distinct value for `a.Id` then `COUNT(DISTINCT a.Id)` won't do it.   `SELECT COUNT (*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100  a.Id ...)` **might** do it but only if you get a [hash match flow distinct](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/12/is-distinct-aggregation-still-considered-harmful.html) so this is unblocking

Comment: I would guess, however, that's likely to do little, @jarlh . I admit I haven't tested, but I would suggest that the data engine would still need to sort the entire result set first to be able to apply the `DISTINCT` operator and then get the `TOP` rows.

Comment: @ThomA, I don't know the SQL Server internals. But "my" dbms would stop reading the tables after 100 distinct values were found.

Comment: @jarlh - It depends how it implements the `DISTINCT` - if it does so by sorting it can't do the sort until it has read all the input rows as the one that sorts first might be the last one read. If it does it by hashing then this can be blocking or unblocking in SQL Server

Comment: You could also just get rid of the `DISTINCT` and use a semi join - `SELECT TOP 100 a.Id
FROM dbo.tableA a
WHERE EXISTS(
SELECT * FROM 
dbo.tableB b 
JOIN dbo.tableC c ON(b.Id = c.tableBId)
WHERE c.User = @user AND d.state = @state AND a.Id = b.tableAId)`

Comment: But anyway all of this stuff will change the query and potentially the execution plan so you will end up optimising something different from the original query. You are probably just best off executing it and viewing the live query plans and looking at the flow of rows there and aborting if it is taking too long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you can optimize in a couple of ways:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) a.Id
    FROM dbo.tableA a
    JOIN dbo.tableB b ON a.Id = b.tableAId
    JOIN dbo.tableC c ON b.Id = c.tableBId
    WHERE c.User = @user
      AND d.state = @state
) a;
```

Alternatively, use some kind of semi-join

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (100) a.*
    FROM dbo.tableA a
    WHERE a.Id IN (
        SELECT b.tableAId
        FROM dbo.tableB b
        JOIN dbo.tableC c ON b.Id = c.tableBId
        WHERE c.User = @user
          AND d.state = @state
    ) a
) a;
```

Both of these would need a non-blocking operator, avoiding a blocking `Sort`, to make any improvement.

If the `TOP` value is [below the estimated number of total unique values](https://www.sql.kiwi/2010/08/row-goals-and-grouping.html), then you may get a `Hash Match Flow Distinct`. Otherwise you are going to need the semi-join, and the right indexes to be able to essentially skip-scan using `Nested Loops` and `Index Seek`.

Comment: Very interesting. I tried the first query you wrote and compared it with the unoptimized query. For a result with count zero. The query cost is 50%/50%. There is a miniscule overhead for the optimized query. For a result with count of 15 000. The cost is 68%/32%. That makes sense, since you do not need to count so many rows. However even for count result of  61, 15 and 3 the query cost were: 69%/31%, 74%/26%, 74%/26% respectively. Meaning it seems to always be better to do a top 100 and wrap the query with a count.

Comment: The execution plans differ a lot. I cannot read them, but the optimized execution plan generally avoids or limits the number of index scans. And instead does index seek. This seems to be a good thing: index seek good, index scan bad.

Comment: Cost % is basically meaningless, use timings and IO statistics. Please share exeecution plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: I cannot share the execution plan. But from testing the actual requests, not just database calls, it did help.

Comment: You can obfuscate them using SentryOne Plan Explorer if necessary